# UWP/WinRT with C++/CX: In a chain of asynchronous tasks, how can data be passed between them?

Tags: asynchronous, lambda, windows-runtime, c++-cx, uwp

I understand that the return from one lambda is fed into the arguments of the next. However, what about if multiple pieces of data need to be passed, or the return type of one lambda is already set by the program structure?

Here is my working code where both of these are the case for opening up a file picker and then reading its contents as text while remembering what the file it came from was:

```
create_task(picker->PickSingleFileAsync())
.then([this](StorageFile^ file) 
    {
        if (file == nullptr) cancel_current_task();
        m_OpenFilename = file->Name;
        return FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file);
    })
.then([this](String^ fileContents)
    {
        //do something with the filename and file contents
    });
```

Note that in order to make this work, I needed to add a class variable to store the filename in between the asynchronous tasks. This strikes me as bad for a number of reasons:

- It is ugly having a class variable for the internal use of a single method
- It this thread-safe? If someone goes nuts opening file pickers and selecting files, would these asynchronous tasks potentially clobber each other when accessing m_OpenFilename?
- This is only a trivial example with one variable, but let's say I also want to keep track of the path of the file, and its file attributes, and a number of other characteristics. Now the class is looking uglier and uglier as the number of class variables increase.

My first approach was to have a variable local in scope to the function, and to pass it into each of the lambda functions by altering their capture lists to be `[this, OpenFilename]`. However, this would fail because by the time the lambda executed, C++/CX's background memory handlers would have already discarded `Openfilename`, resulting in an access violation when accessing it.

In my example, how can I pass the metadata of the file along to the results of `ReadTextAsync` so that I can have access to both the file and its contents at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just continue building a chain of nested continuations:

```
auto picker = ref new FileOpenPicker();
picker->FileTypeFilter->Append(L".txt");
picker->SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId::Desktop;
auto task = create_task(picker->PickSingleFileAsync()).then(
  [](StorageFile^ file)
{
  auto name = file->Name;
  auto task = create_task(file->OpenReadAsync()).then(
    [name](IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType^ iras)
  {
    OutputDebugString(name->Data());
  });
});
```

If you don't want to do that (for whatever reason) another option is to use a `shared_ptr` to hold the value; in this case I'm going to hold on to the name and the created date in a helper `file_info` type:

```
struct file_info
{
  Platform::String^ name;
  Windows::Foundation::DateTime created;
};

auto picker = ref new FileOpenPicker();
picker->FileTypeFilter->Append(L".txt");
picker->SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId::Desktop;
auto info = std::make_shared<file_info>();

auto task = create_task(picker->PickSingleFileAsync()).then(
  [info](StorageFile^ file) 
{
  info->name = file->Name;
  info->created = file->DateCreated;
  return create_task(file->OpenReadAsync());
}).then(
  [info](IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType^ iras)
  {
    OutputDebugString(info->name->Data());
    OutputDebugString(L"\n");
    wchar_t datetime[100];
    _i64tow_s(info->created.UniversalTime, datetime, 100, 10);
    OutputDebugString(datetime);
});
```